# Google AppScript to Lock Specific Rows & Columns

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using below app script to lock Google Sheet. The script locks till the last row having data and other rows are open to edit. Further few users as specified in script can edit the locked range. Every time the script runs, it deletes the old lock and creates a new lock to ensure there is only one lock. The script is working perfect in all aspects as desired. Now I want to add one things in the script as below:

I want to exclude first 5 rows and column No. Q to column T from the lock i.e. when the script runs it should not lock (1) row number 1 to 5 and (2) column Q to T. Am attaching a link of reference spreed sheet having sample data, in this sheet when the script will run it will lock from row no. 6 to 1001 (because 1001 is the last row with data) and will lock columns A to P ( i.e. columns Q to T will not be locked).

I had checked the community for this issue but could not get the perfect solution for the same.

Any help on above will be appreciated.

Reference spread sheet link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gWuoYIAi7eTgbgfk_2H31ITKUH3WOnL9v94MpWBqAYo/edit#gid=0

```
function installedOnOpen(e) {
const editors = 
["abc@abc.com","xyz@xyz.com"]; // Added: Please set the email addresses you want to 
give the permission as the editor.

const sheetNames = ["SO"]; // Please set the sheet names you want to protect.
const sheets = e.source.getSheets().filter(s => 
sheetNames.includes(s.getSheetName()));
if (sheets.length == 0) return;
sheets.forEach(s => {
const p = s.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
if (p.length > 0) {
  p.forEach(pp => pp.remove());
}
const lastRow = s.getLastRow();
if (lastRow != 0) {
  const newProtect = s.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, s.getMaxColumns()).protect();
  newProtect.removeEditors(newProtect.getEditors());
  newProtect.addEditors(editors); // Added
  if (newProtect.canDomainEdit()) newProtect.setDomainEdit(false);
}
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Google Sheets: Lock Specific Rows & Columns

You may add the following to your last conditional statement to achieve what you'd like to do:

```
  const startRow = 6;
  const startCol = 1;
  const numRows = lastRow - 4;
  const numCols = s.getMaxColumns() - 4;
```

The full code would become:

```
function installedOnOpen(e) {
  const editors = ["abc@abc.com", "xyz@xyz.com"];
  const sheetNames = ["SO"];
  const sheets = e.source.getSheets().filter(s => sheetNames.includes(s.getSheetName()));
  if (sheets.length == 0)
    return;

  sheets.forEach(s => {
    const p = s.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
    if (p.length > 0) {
      p.forEach(pp => pp.remove());
    }

    const lastRow = s.getLastRow();
    if (lastRow != 0) {
      const startRow = 6;
      const startCol = 1;
      const numRows = lastRow - 4;
      const numCols = s.getMaxColumns() - 4;
      const newProtect = s.getRange(startRow, startCol, numRows, numCols).protect();
      newProtect.removeEditors(newProtect.getEditors());
      newProtect.addEditors(editors);
      if (newProtect.canDomainEdit()) newProtect.setDomainEdit(false);
    }
  });
}
```

#### OUTPUT

[image: OUTPUT]

#### REFERENCE

- [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

Comment: @ Saddles thank you for the super quick, wonderful and perfect solution.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that your issue's been resolved! You can always set those directly if you don't like the additional lines. `s.getRange(6, 1, lastRow - 4, s.getMaxColumns() - 4).protect();`