# Google Sheet Lock Range To Be Considering By Excluding Few Columns

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the script given in the below link to solve my issue,

[Google AppScript to Lock Specific Rows & Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78067805/google-appscript-to-lock-specific-rows-columns/78068228?noredirect=1#comment137629533_78068228)

This script works as below:

It locks the sheet till the last row having data E.g. if Row No. 1001 is last row with data then it will lock rows till 1001 (excluding top 5 rows and few columns as specified in script).

Now I want to make below change in the script.

E.g. if there are 1000 rows in the sheet and 18 columns. Column No. 1 to 16 have data till row No. 101 and column 17 and 18 has data in all the rows i.e. in all 1000 rows. To check the last row with data (to apply lock) I do not want to consider Column 17 and 18 but need to consider only Column 1 to 16, thus the script should lock data till row no. 101 only.

Am attaching a sample sheet for reference.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/126UwtWmgEtJRCblXmvd7WJQKtjATR0ygEir-mXuYC0Q/edit#gid=0

Any support on above will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Workaround: Count the non-empty rows in columns 1 - 16

The way I've approached this is to get all of the rows with data then count the non-empty rows from column 1 - 16.

I've slightly modified the answer in your previous question to the following:

```
function installedOnOpen(e) {
  const editors = ["abc@abc.com", "xyz@xyz.com"];
  const sheetNames = ["Sheet1"];
  const sheets = e.source.getSheets().filter(s => sheetNames.includes(s.getSheetName()));
  if (sheets.length == 0)
    return;

  sheets.forEach(s => {
    const p = s.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
    if (p.length > 0) {
      p.forEach(pp => pp.remove());
    }


    // Gets all the values from col1 to col16 up to the last row 
    var range = s.getRange(1, 1, s.getLastRow(), 16).getValues();
    var lastRow = range.length - 1;

    /*
    the for loop below checks the rows from the bottom up 
    and will stop once it encounters a non-empty row.
    This mimics the behavior of the getLastRow() method 
    but restricts it to columns 1 - 16
    */

    for (lastRow; lastRow > 0; lastRow--) {
      if (range[lastRow].join('').length > 0) break;
    }

    if (lastRow != 0) {
      const startRow = 6;
      const numRows = lastRow - 4;
      const newProtect = s.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 16).protect();
      newProtect.removeEditors(newProtect.getEditors());
      newProtect.addEditors(editors); // Added
      if (newProtect.canDomainEdit()) newProtect.setDomainEdit(false);
    }
  });
}
```

I'm getting the following result when the script's installed as an onOpen trigger in your sample sheet:
[image]

Comment: @ DuuEny Thank you for super fast and perfect solution, it works excellent as expected. Bravo....